# Visual Studio debugger: Break on entering an external function?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints, source-server

With "[Just My Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx)" turned off and a source location/server, it's easy to step into functions that are not in your code. Is there a way to set a breakpoint on one of these, though?

Basically, I want to say "when this function is called from anywhere, break and show me the source". I tried the "set function breakpoint" and entering the fully-qualified name of the function, however it said it couldn't find the function.