# Visual Studio Debugger not breaking when function (in external .net dll) is hit

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

I followed the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377382/visual-studio-debugger-break-on-entering-an-external-function) to break when a function defined in an external dll is hit, however its not working for me. Maybe I am missing a setting. How can I get it to work?

Checklist:
- Enable just my code is disabled
- Symbols for external dll (System.Data.Entity.dll) appear to have been loaded (see below)

[image]

EDIT: the answer is to compile the code as 32 bit. It worked for me, can't say if it will work for others.

Some notes: There is a useful tool to know about. Its called `srctool.exe`. It comes with Debugging Tools for Windows and got installed under `c:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\srcsrv` on my machine. You can run it on a pdb file and it will tell you whether file has been source indexed or not. If the pdb file is source-indexed, then there is a link embedded in the pdb file which points to a location from where the source code can be fetched. E.g., I see this output from srctool.exe:

```
[f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\DataEntity\System\Data\Objects\DataClasses\RelatedEnd.cs] trg: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/source/NET/4.5/net//ndp/fx/src/DataEntity/System/Data/Objects/DataClasses/RelatedEnd.cs/550320/RelatedEnd.cs
```

What if pdb file is not source indexed? Does it mean VS will not be able to show you the source, step-in etc.? I think so, though I am not an expert. I found [this](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx) link to be semi-useful.

Anyway, coming back, for me, fetching code from the embedded link in pdb file meant running this command (VS will give you a popup where it will ask you to run the command; if it fails you won't know; only way to know if it succeeded is to run it yourself from a console) which gave an error.

```
tf.exe view /version:550320 /noprompt “$/[omitted]/[file].cs” /server:http://[omitted] /console > [file.cs]
```

To get around this limitation, I manually downloaded .net framework source code from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx. There was a problem here also: the file gets downloaded as .aspx which doesn't do anything. Turns out you have to rename to .msi. Then run the executable. See this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/refsourceserver/thread/f17c11c1-72f6-4529-bafe-5a1d79b72bd7

I just can't believe how many issues I ran into.

Comment: I can't read the screen shot.

Comment: Tried it without the parenthesis at the end?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. In fact I also tried instructions on this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx but still didn't work